# Cloudflare 521 Error when using AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, cloudflare

After deploying an API Gateway function in front of a Lambda function, and setting it up with Cloudflare, I keep getting 521 errors from Cloudflare.

I have completed all the necessary steps such as generated a certificate, created the custom domain in API Gateway, etc.

Why would I be getting a 521 error when using AWS API Gateway with Cloudflare?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that in Cloudflare the SSL setting **must** be set to `Full` or `Full (strict)`. Otherwise you will get a 521 error from Cloudflare.

This is because AWS API Gateway does not allow HTTP connections and requires HTTPS connections. With HTTPS set to `Off` or `Flexible` in Cloudflare, it will not connect via HTTPS, and therefore fail to connect to AWS.

Of course it is recommended to use `Full (strict)` to ensure extra security on your site.